# Add text in @Html.TextAreaFor MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create the textarea field at my form

```
 <textarea class="img-shadow" cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" rows="2">Message</textarea>
```

I write code

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "img-shadow" })
```

but I get empty textarea without any text

```
 <textarea class="img-shadow" cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" rows="2"></textarea>
```

How can I add text in?

Comment: does the model that is being sent through defiantly have a value in it through debug?

Comment: Are you sure that `model.Message` has a value?

Comment: I dont need a value, because if I have a value, I get `<textarea class="img-shadow" cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" rows="2" value="added text"></textarea>`, but I need no value, I need text inside textarea tags like `<textarea>text</textarea>`

Comment: Just bind value to model before call view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of the text box will be whatever the value of `model.Message` is.

This should be set in your `Action` method in the `Controller`, and passed to the `View`

```
public ViewResult ActionName() {
    var model = new ViewModel(); 
    model.Message = "Text Area Content"; 
    return View(model); 
}
```

As a test just output `model.Message` in the `View`, it will be empty.

```
 <p>@Model.Message</p>
```

Then `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "img-shadow" })` will output

```
 <textarea class="img-shadow" cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" rows="2">Text Area Content</textarea>
```

Comment: To expand on this solution -- if you use the overload specifying rows/columns with null htmlAttributes like `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Prop, 20, 40, null)` then it seems to throw out the default value of the model.  Using `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Prop, new { rows=20, cols=40 })` instead should work.

Comment: 100% Correct best answer

Answer (score 3):

After much scratching around I managed to get it done this way.

```
@{ var _address="Line 1\nLine 2\n Line 3"; }

@Html.TextArea(Model.xxxx , new { id="address" } )
<script>
var x = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode( _address )) ;
document.getElementById("address").value = x;
</script>
```

If you haven't any control characters like newline \n you can replace var x=@Html...... with var x = "Text" ;

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "img-shadow", value = "added text" })
```

But If you initialize your model in controller Get method, then it will add text to your textarea, automaticly.

Check [these](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) tutorials

Comment: Nope, I tried that, it doesnt work, I get just `<textarea class="img-shadow" cols="20" id="Message" name="Message" rows="2" value="added text"></textarea>` but without any text inside again.

Comment: I cant undestand, I have in my controller this code `[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Contacts()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contacts(FeedbackForm Model)
        {...}` Where and how should I define the text for my textarea?

Answer (score 1):

you add the default value into it.. by

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "img-shadow",@value = "added text" })
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller Write

```
ModelVariable.Message= Server.HtmlDecode(ModelVariable.Message);

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "img-shadow" })
```

It has worked for me